# CakePHP 3 Paginator using FIELD() in ORDER clause

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I have a question regarding the Paginator Component of CakePHP3 (3.0.13). I'm using the MYSQL function `FIELD()` to order my data, like that:

```
$this->paginate = array_merge_recursive([
      'conditions' => [
           'zip IN' => $zips
      ],
           'order' => [
                  'FIELD(zip, '.rtrim(implode(',', $zips), ',').')',
                  'ispro' => 'desc',
           ],
           $this->paginate
     ]);
```

When I apply this to my `$this->paginate()` it wouldn't be recognized as long as the query param `sort` is set. To avoid this I remove the `sort` in my request with:

```
if (isset($this->request->query['sort'])) {
      unset($this->request->query['sort']);
}
```

This is working, but I was wondering if there is a better solution, maybe in the paginator component itself, which I haven't found yet.

Comment: please mention your cakephp version. Also post the code where you use FIELD() function

Comment: I'm using cake 3.0.13.

Comment: I guess you should add your calculated field to sortWhitelist option

Comment: You mean like `$this->paginate('sortWhitelist' =>[ 'zip']);`? Already tried that, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: you are creating a new calculated field. So you should do `$this->paginate('sortWhitelist' =>[ 'FIELD(zip, '.rtrim(implode(',', $zips), ',').')'])`

Comment: Won't work :( I have had a look into the PaginatorComponent. In `PaginatorComponent::validateSort()` the sort query parameter will be taken and put into the order field. So my values applied in `$this->paginate = ['order' => ...]` are overwritten. I don't know if thats intended, because I won't see a possibility to apply custom order mechanics on top of a pagination sort.

Comment: So maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to achieve: you want to sort by FIELD() even when you have a sort param in your query string? Can you please try to explain, maybe with an example?

Comment: If it is possible I would like to deactivate the sorting capability of the Paginator completely, but I as far as I know thats not possible. I have a list of dentists, which are classified as normal dentists and pro dentists. So I always want to order the ispro Field DESC (I have updated my question with that) and the dentists in a given perimeter for a location/zip should also be displayed in the direction the zips are found, which I achieve by using the FIELD() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can sort your query before you paginate it. Your sort conditions will come before the one appended from the paginator component

so you can do

```
$dentists = $this->Dentists->find()
    ->order([
        'FIELD(zip, '.rtrim(implode(',', $zips), ',').')',
        'ispro' => 'desc'
     ]);

$this->paginate = array_merge_recursive([
    'conditions' => [
        'zip IN' => $zips
    ],
    $this->paginate
 ]); 

$dentists = $this->paginate($dentists);
```

Comment: Good idea. So Paginator would take the resultSet $dentists and paginate over that, instead of doing a find() on its own, correct?

Comment: right. Actually `$dentist` is a query object (not a recordset) and `paginate()` just return another $query object obtained appending order and page conditions to `$dentists`